# how to write yuv422 image data to bmp file?

Tags: file, bmp, yuv

I have image data in yuv422 format in EEPROM using at91sam9260 using image sensor interface (ISI). 
i want to write it to SD-card in .bmp format? 
Or i have to first convert yuv422 image to RGB and then i have to process data to write BMP file?  I have to do it in C.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to convert it. The BMP file format only supports RGB image data.

If you don't want to do the conversion on your microprocessor (hint: you probably don't), you can just write out the YUV data to a file on the SD card -- call it a `.yuv` file, if you like -- and do the conversion on your PC. That'll probably be much easier.

Comment: can you please help me out, if i have RGB data in EEPROM, how can i write  bmp file in SD-CARD?